# Не фильтруются карточки на WP, в чем причина?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Почему код отказывается фильтровать карточки?

Идея фильтра такая:
На странице, есть горизонтальный фильтр, который фильтрует по произвольным полям (плагин acf).
Контент фильтруется по таким полям как:

- Sity_contest (город) - выпадающий список городов из БД
- data_cont (дата) - календарь с выделенными датами или диапазон дат
- name_contest (название) - выпадающий список

Увы, из того, что я сделал, появляется только форма фильтра.
Собственно код:

```
<!-- Фильтр -->
<form id="filter-form">
  <div class="filter-group">
    <label for="sity-contest-filter">Город:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sity-contest-filter" name="sity_contest">
  </div>
  <div class="filter-group">
    <label for="data-cont-filter">Дата:</label>
    <input type="text" id="data-cont-filter" name="data_cont">
  </div>
  <div class="filter-group">
    <label for="name-contest-filter">Название:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name-contest-filter" name="name_contest">
  </div>
  <div class="filter-group">
    <label for="judges-at-the-competition-filter">Судьи:</label>
    <input type="text" id="judges-at-the-competition-filter" name="judges_at_the_competition">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Применить фильтр</button>
</form>

<div class="rotate-block">
  <?php
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'cards',
      'posts_per_page' => -1 // Все посты
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) :
      while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $sityContest = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Sity_contest', true);
        $dataCont = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'data_cont', true);
        $nameContest = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'name_contest', true);
        $judgesAtTheCompetition = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'judges-at-the-competition', true);
  ?>
        
  <?php
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
      echo 'Нет доступных карточек.';
    endif;
  ?>
</div>
<!-- Конец фильтра -->


<!-- Вкладки-->

<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-menu tab-list">
    <li class="tab-list__item active"><a href="#will-be">Будет</a></li>
    <li><a href="#was">Было</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content active" id="will-be">
    <div class="rotate-block">
      <?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cards', // Тип записи
        'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
        'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' => 'data_cont', // Поле даты
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'), // Только даты, которые еще не наступили
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATETIME'
          )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'data_cont',
        'order' => 'ASC'
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);

      if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
          get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'cards');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
      else :
        echo '<p>Нет записей для отображения</p>';
      endif;
      ?>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab-content" id="was">
    <div class="rotate-block">
      <?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cards', // Тип записи
        'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
        'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' => 'data_cont', // Поле даты
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'), // Только даты, которые уже прошли
            'compare' => '<',
            'type' => 'DATETIME'
          )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'data_cont',
        'order' => 'DESC'
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);

      if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
          get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'cards');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
      else :
        echo '<p>Нет записей для отображения</p>';
      endif;
      ?>
    </div>
    <div class="load">
      <button id="show-more">Показать ещё</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

function.php:

```
function enqueue_filter_scripts() {
    function apply_filter() {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'cards',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // Все посты
            'meta_query' => array(),
        );
    
        if (isset($_POST['sity_contest']) && !empty($_POST['sity_contest'])) {
            $sityContest = sanitize_text_field($_POST['sity_contest']);
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'Sity_contest',
                'value' => $sityContest,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
        }
    
        if (isset($_POST['data_cont']) && !empty($_POST['data_cont'])) {
            $dataCont = sanitize_text_field($_POST['data_cont']);
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'data_cont',
                'value' => $dataCont,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
        }
    
        if (isset($_POST['name_contest']) && !empty($_POST['name_contest'])) {
            $nameContest = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name_contest']);
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'name_contest',
                'value' => $nameContest,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
        }
    
        if (isset($_POST['judges_at_the_competition']) && !empty($_POST['judges_at_the_competition'])) {
            $judgesAtTheCompetition = sanitize_text_field($_POST['judges_at_the_competition']);
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'judges-at-the-competition',
                'value' => $judgesAtTheCompetition,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
        }
    
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
    
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="change-img">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo 'Нет доступных карточек.';
        endif;
    
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_apply_filter', 'apply_filter');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_apply_filter', 'apply_filter');
}
```

Ну и JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#filter-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var filterData = $(this).serialize();

    $('.rotate-block .change-img').hide();

    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'
      type: 'POST'
      data: filterData + '&action=apply_filter',
      success: function(response) {
        $('.rotate-block').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```